# Working with an img within an HTML element

Tags: html, css

I am currently editing a portfolio website template. I am attempting to adjust the position of the image within an HTML element without adjusting the entire grey box behind it. Essentially I want the photo of the person to be pushed to the left while everything else (greybox, text, etc) stays in the same position. I added "left -500px" to the style sheet and it moved the entire HTML element.

```css
.front-person-img{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:15;
    -webkit-transition:height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
    -moz-transition:height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
    transition:height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
    margin:200px auto;
    margin-bottom:0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    border-radius:0;
}
.front-person-img > img{
max-width:100%;
left:-45px;
top:40px;
position:relative;
vertical-align:bottom;
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(40px);
-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(40px);
-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(40px);
-o-transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(40px);
transform:rotate(-45deg) translateY(40px);
}
```

```html
<div class='front-person-img' >
                        
                        <!--person's image-->
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/LrfnV0Q/IMG-5876.jpg" alt="IMG-5876" border="0"></a>
                        <!--/person's image-->
                        
                    </div>
```

lastly, an image of what I am trying to do.

[image: normal position]

[image: position pushed left]

visit this link for image https://ibb.co/JqP5Dcx

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet, which will show what the code does when clicking Run code snippet... if the code is valid. Currently, it is not (missing the ending `}` in CSS, then ending `</div>` in HTML). Also, if you don't have an absolute URL to use for the image, use a dummy image site to use one of similar proportions.

Comment: For the question, if you want to affect the position of the `img` element, select that element. Your CSS currently selects the wrapping `div` (so add `.front-person-img img { left: -500px; position: absolute; }` or whatever.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Okay, I understand so .front-person-img is only selecting the class which was made within the css code not the image that was added later with the img tag. So you have to add img to select that image

Comment: @HereticMonkey something like the link I added at bottom of question? In regards to dummy image site

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am unsure why the person image gets so large and turned when running the html/css in this snippet. Same image I have in my directory and html/css code in my project. However, when I run in brackets I receive output to what I included in the original jpegs. I would think it has something to do with the addition of other html/css code in my project

Comment: to fine tune my question I guess I don't under stand why the image is sideways when running the snippet in here but when opening the index.html it is normal.. Same code

Answer (score 1):

Per one of the most recent comments, if you target the img element inside the div and add some styles you should get the expected result. Run the code snippet below to review the expected layout. I adjusted some values for this quick example but you should be able to recycle the CSS for your webpage.

```css
.front-person-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
  transition: height .5s .3s ease, transform .5s .8s ease;
  margin: 200px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 0;
}

.front-person-img img {
  width: 215px;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="front-person-img">
  <img src="https://upleap.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/how-to-create-the-perfect-instagram-profile-picture.jpg" alt="Profile Picture">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! yes thank you that was the problem, I forgot to add additional css code which had the img targeted.

Comment: My problem was that I was attempting to edit the css without the img selected.. ".front-person-img" once I started adding the code to shift the img within the ".front-person-img > img" it started working.